# Need help fixing Kivy KV file styling

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on a little game in Kivy.  Below is my current styling file. I want to have the enemies spawn with a different image, or at least a modified version of the image they are currently assigned.  I tried just adding another styling rule to the enemy class, but it just overrides the former one.  I also tried importing a random module to the KV file and using an if statement for random selection, but you can't import random to a KV file as I found out.  I'm not sure what else to try.  I can't find anything in the Kivy docs on it.

```
#: kivy 1.0.9

<Enemy>:
    size: 50,50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            source: "myimage.png"
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    size: 50,50

<Player>:
    size: 50,50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            source: "playerimage.png"
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos


<Game>:
    player1: player_shooter
    size: 800, 800
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: "bg.png"
            size: self.width, self.height

    Player:
        id: player_shooter
        pos: self.pos

    Label:
        font_size: 30
        center_x: root.width * 6.6/8
        top: root.top - 10
        text: "Score-Place-Holder"

    Label:
        font_size: 30
        center_x: root.width / 6
        top: root.top - 10
        text: "Lives-Place-Holder"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example (that will show the syntax you need):

```
#:import random random
<Enemy>:
    size: 50,50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            source: random.choice(["myimage.png", "anotherimage.png"])
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    size: 50,50
```